# Load External HTML Using JavaScript Script (via Embedded Code in Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, elementor, weebly

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I need to create web pages in Wordpress where I can add embedded code (JavaScript) in numerous places on a web page in order to read in external HTML files into each embedded code section.

The reason that I need this is because I create numerous HTML files, with updated data, on a daily basis.

I currently use the following embedded JavaScript code on each webpage on a Weebly website where all the web pages read in and are updated with the new data in the uploaded HTML file (INCL files, in this example):

**JavaScript to read HTML files (INCL files) into embedded code section (example)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#TODAYS-RACE-TIMES-HOME-PAGE').show().load('files/theme/TODAYS-RACE-TIMES-HOME-PAGE.incl');
      });
    </script>
<div id='TODAYS-RACE-TIMES-HOME-PAGE'></div>
```

**HTML file (INCL file example) (as mentioned above)**

```
<!-- TODAYS-RACE-TIMES-HOME-PAGE.incl created by C:\Users\billy\Dropbox\THIRD-DIVIDEND\PRODUCTION\TODAY\HOME-SCREEN-RACE-LIST.pl -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<p><font face="Lato"><font size="2"><font color="#07342a"><b>7 RACES AT GOULBURN (NSW) - RACE 1 STARTS AT 1:15 PM AEST</b></p>
<p><font face="Lato"><font size="2"><font color="#07342a"><b>8 RACES AT PAKENHAM SYNTHETIC (VIC) - RACE 1 STARTS AT 1:00 PM AEST</b></p>
</html>
```

Once published, the Weebly web pages are automatically populated with the newly uploaded data in the HTML files.

I need to create the same setup on a Wordpress website using Elementor.

Thank you in advance. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simply add the javascript to the page in your plugin/theme.

Comment: Fyi, simply adding the aforementioned JavaScript code to an HTML widget in Wordpress does not work, hence, the rewrite of the functionality in HTML. If anyone knows of a “tried-and-tested” way to get the JavaScript code to work in multiple places on a webpage via embedded code (e.g. WPCode, etc.), I’m all ears. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to drop elementor HTML widget on the page. Then paste this code in the Elementor HTML widget:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#TODAYS-RACE-TIMES-HOME-PAGE').load('files/theme/TODAYS-RACE-TIMES-HOME-PAGE.incl');
  });
</script>
```

Now you can duplicate this widget and change the id "TODAYS-RACE-TIMES-HOME-PAGE"
It is tested and working perfectly.

Comment: Hi Ahmer, Thanks for your responses. Unfortunately, this is not working. I have created a new blank page in Wordpress and have edited the page with Elementor to simply drop an HTML widget on the top of the page, added the code but nothing is appearing on the page (both in Firefox and Google Chrome). The HTML (and INCL, tested with both) files have definitely been uploaded to the website. It seems pretty straightforward. Any suggestion why it wouldn't be working?

Comment: Hi Billy! Have a look please:
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/20811678?key=9da827b1c919ce2c7ae91413d02c2e6d
Make sure the file url is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the video @ahmer I stand corrected. I created a new page, added a new HTML widget, inserted the JavaScript code (jQuery(document).ready(function($) included). I also cleaned up the HTML to simply include <html>, <body> and <p> tags and now, it's working. Not exactly sure why it wasn't working earlier except to say that the HTML didn't include the <body> tag. Hard to tell at the stage. Anyway, thank you for all your help. Unfortunately, I don't see the Bounty Points included in my post anymore. If you know of a way for me to transfer the points to you, please let me know. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I rewrote the code using HTML (instead of the JavaScript) using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js instead of https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/d3js/7.8.5/d3.min.js and it appears to be working now:

Note: For some reason, this did not work using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/d3js/7.8.5/d3.min.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   $('#TODAYS-RACE-TITLE-OUTFILE').load("TODAYS-RACE-TITLE-OUTFILE.html");

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="TODAYS-RACE-TITLE-OUTFILE"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Onwards and upwards!